# Log4j2 kafka appender failover is not working and with this error "Broker may not be available"

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j2

I have this log4j2.xml file I don't understand why Failover appender is not working when Kafka appender is failing.
My Kafka appender is:

```
<Kafka name="kafka" topic="myTopic" ignoreExceptions="false" >
   <JsonLayout />
   <Property name="bootstrap.servers">127.0.0.1:9092</Property>
</Kafka>
```

My Failover appender is:

```
<FailOver name="fail-over" primary="kafka" ignoreExceptions="false">
   <Failovers>
         <AppenderRef ref="randomFile" />            
    </Failovers>
</FailOver>
```

My root level is:

```
<Root level="info" includeLocation="false">
  <AppenderRef ref="fail-over" />
</Root>
```

But for some reason I keep getting connection refusal error which exactly is:

```
16:32:05.669 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with /127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:526)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:561)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:327)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:242)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```